# Performing a fresh WiX Toolset 4.0 installation?

Tags: wix, wix4

I'm trying to install the recently released WiX Toolset v4 and not having any luck.

According to [the docs](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/intro/), "The wix.exe tool requires the .NET SDK, version 6 or later." I installed the .NET SDK 7.0 [via winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&tabs=net70#install-with-windows-package-manager-winget) and ran the command to install WiX only to receive the following errors:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet>dotnet.exe tool install --global wix --version 4.0.0

C:\...\restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'wix (>= 4.0.0)' for 'net7.0'.
C:\...\restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'wix (>= 4.0.0)' for 'net7.0/any'.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'wix' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

I removed the .NET SDK v7, installed v6, tried the WiX install again, and got the similar results. Also tried removing the `--version` to see if it would install any version of the WiX Toolset, but no such luck:

```
C:\...\restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'wix (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net6.0'.
C:\...\restore.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'wix (>= 0.0.0)' for 'net6.0/any'.
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or missing here? The statements to install seem fairly straightforward, but the errors (and the accompanying [error documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues)) aren't much help (to me, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `dotnet nuget list source` list `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`? The WiX tool NuGet package is on nuget.org so you have to include the NuGet.org feed in your source list.

You can also run

```
dotnet tool install --verbosity detailed --global wix --version 4.0.0
```

to get more detail about the attempt. It includes a list of feeds, too:

```
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: `dotnet nuget list source` lists a whole bunch o' nuthin (i.e. "No sources found."). 

Ran `dotnet nuget add source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"`, tried the `tool install` command again and it worked like a charm. Thanks!